# Using Liquibase to Add a Create Date - Database Agnostic

Tags: mysql, oracle, liquibase, database-administration

I am using Liquibase to delete a specific row if it exists.

For a potential rollback I want to re-insert the row.  One of the columns is CREATEDATE which is basically the current time.

Due to business reasons I cannot assume the database this runs against is an Oracle or a mySQL database.

Is there a way I can insert the current date by either using server time or including both oracle and mySQL values?

Currently I have

```
  <!-- NOW = CREATE_DATE FOR ROLLBACK -->  
  <property name="now" value="sysdate" dbms="oracle"/>
  <property name="now" value="now()" dbms="mysql"/>
```

and in rollback

```
<column name="CREATEDATE" valueDate="${now}" />
```

Will this always default to mySQL time? Will it give me a value depending on which DBMS is being used?

Ideally I would rather use server time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liquibase should convert the string "current_datetime" in a valueDate tag to be the database-specific current time function without any additional configuration.

Current_datetime will work basically the same as your current setup, however. In both cases the date/time saved will be the server time not the client time.